# Fixing StackOverflowError in Java

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I'm a bit new at stacks so I'm not quite sure I fully understand what the StackOverflowError entails. I did read that it mostly occurs in recursion that never ends.

```
public double calculateLeibniz(double pi, double x, long l) {
    if (l == 10000) {
        return pi;
    }
    if (l % 2 == 0) {
        pi -= (1.0/x);
        return calculateLeibniz(pi, x + 2.0, l + 1);
    } else {
        pi += (1.0/x);
        return calculateLeibniz(pi, x + 2.0, l + 1);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to calculate PI using the Leibniz method and figured I'd try to flex my recursion muscles. I'm not sure why it returns the error as the method is set to terminate after 10000 iterations. Is there an error in that itself where using a loop would be more efficient?

Comment: Well yes, you're recursing 10,000 times which means you're building up a stack of all those 10,000 calls. One reason to avoid recursion is precisely because it does this, and the code will fail if you run out of stack space - which is what's apparently happening. The recursion doesn't have to be infinite to cause problems - just big enough that you run out of stack space.

Comment: it doesn't necessarily mean the recursion doesn't end.  you might just have too many iterations for your memory to handle.  Try terminating after 100 to see if this fixes the error

Comment: Recursion is often a monkey solution.  Situations like yours are just as easily solved using iteration.

Comment: For some weird reason some educators insist on demonstrating recursion with problems that, while mathematically recursively defined, are better solved iteratively.  This is a shame as there are many problems in computer science that _are_ intrinsically recursive and for which recursion is highly appropriate.

Comment: The same recursive solution in scheme or some other tail recursive language will work fine. We're quick to poo-poo recursion because our language doesn't optimize it.

Answer (score 2):

10000 is a pretty deep stack! The JVM is undoubtedly bombing out before you reach your "limit". I propose that you re-implement your method iteratively rather than recursively. Something like this...

```
public double calculateLeibniz(double pi, double x, int l) {
    while (l < 10000) {
        if (l % 2 == 0) {
            pi -= 1.0/x;
        } else {
            pi += 1.0/x;
        }
        x += 2.0;
        ++l;
    }
    return pi;
}
```

In this case, your algorithm's stack depth is very shallow: 1 stack frame deep, to be specific.